# Как заменить последнюю строку?

Tags: javascript, replace

Скрипт меняет первую строку которая совпадает с переменной `mx`, а нужно заменить последнюю совпадающую строку с переменной `mx`.
За ответ спасибо заранее.

```js
var str = document.getElementById('inp').value,
    mx = '200',
    dx = '900';
str = str.replace(mx, dx);
document.getElementById('out').value = str;
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="10" id="inp">200
500
200
400</textarea>
<textarea  rows="5" cols="10" id="out"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = document.getElementById('inp').value,
    mx = '200',
    dx = '900';
str = str.split("\n").reverse().join("\n").
          replace(mx, dx).
          split("\n").reverse().join("\n");
document.getElementById('out').value = str;
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="10" id="inp">200
500
200
400</textarea>
<textarea  rows="5" cols="10" id="out"></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно регуляркой:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(mx + '$'), dx);
```

Только учтите, что в строках, более сложных, чем `200`, может понадобиться экранировать служебные для регулярок символы.